# jQuery example cant be understood the role of attr and split as well as classNames[1]

Tags: jquery

Hello guys I have stuck with this example I dont understand what happens after assigning the var classNames. What role plays the attr("class") and split?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box").on("click", function() {
   
      var classNames = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
      $("." + classNames[1]).css("background-color", "red");

  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Before asking questions, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). When asking a question, you need to be able to specify a problem and a desired outcome. In your case, some Googling and a look thru the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName) would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, both methods have different "roles".

The attr() method is used to get attribute values-in particular, the value associated with "class". The attr() method is typically used in DOM manipulation.

The split() method is used to split text or put another way to split a string into an array of substrings. The split() method does not modify the original string but returns a new array

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example. `attr("class")` gets all the classes the tag has and `split` makes an array of them so you can reference them by index: `classNames[1]`

In this example, `classNames[1]` is the class `center` and adding `.css("background-color", "red");` to it is equivalent to `.center{ background-color:red; }`

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.box {
    color: green;
    font-size: 32px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button class="box center" value="click">Click</button>
<script>

$(".box").on("click", function() {
      console.log($(this).attr("class")); //returns 'box center'
      var classNames = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
      console.log(classNames); //returns ['box', 'center']
      $("." + classNames[1]).css("background-color", "red");
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```